# DataTables - Show alert when clicking "aLengthMenu"

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the plugin  https://datatables.net/
i want to add onclick on aLengthMenu and show the chosen value with alert here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var oTable = $('# Table_id').DataTable({ 
         'iDisplayLength': '50', 
         "aLengthMenu": [ [20, 50, 100, 200], [20, 50, 100, 200] ]
        }); 
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings(); 
var x = oSettings._iDisplayLength; });
```

Comment: Why you write "aLengthMenu"? On the docs it seems it's called "lengthMenu" ==> https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate your click event

**HTML**

```
<table id="dataTable">...</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() { 
     var oTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({ 
         'iDisplayLength': '50', 
         "aLengthMenu": [
             [20, 50, 100, 200],
             [20, 50, 100, 200] 
         ]
     }); 
     var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings(); 
     var x = oSettings._iDisplayLength; 

    $(document).on("change", ".dataTables_length select", function(){
          var selectedVal = $(this).val();
          alert(selectedVal);
    });

});
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/3jowrb4q/